# Android custom camera preview?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am creating a `camera` application for `android`.
I want my `camera preview` activity like picture below (for example). I want to divide my `camera preview` activity in four parts or many.

That is, after I click a picture from `camera`, when I am back to my (camera image preview activity) `activity`, I want to have the activity `screen` divided into four parts or more, and each part should have that `preview image` on it.

Reason for that is that I want to experiment each of the preview with image `render-script` effects [but that solution is beyond the scope of my question, as I know how to use render-scripts], and that, each part should have separate `rendering`.

Can any one help me to find a solution for this?

[image: Four image previews instead of one, after taking picture from camera]

It will be a great help if there is any example or tutorial for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want onClick of these four parts?

Comment: i want preview divided in four parts on my camera surface and when picture taken save with this effect.

Answer (score 3):

After trying hard, I found the solution. Yeaahhhh!!!

camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clickButton"
        style="@android:style/Animation.Translucent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Camera Activity should be like this: I am posting only that part which I think is the main part where you should focus, the rest you can implement. If you stuck somewhere please ask me.
First you should call from your activity:

```
final Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
            clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });
```

your onPictureTaken() should be like this:

```
/**
     * This will be called after taking picture from camera.
     */
    final transient private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        /**
         * After taking picture, onPictureTaken() will be called where image
         * will be saved.
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        mGetFile));
                outStream.write(data); // Write the data to corresponding place.
                ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview))
                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLayout))
                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Options options = new Options();
                options.inScaled = true;
                options.inPurgeable = true;

                // to scale the image to 1/8
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                        data.length, options);
                ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
                ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
                ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
                ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);

                image1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                image2.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                image3.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                image4.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                camera.release();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                camera.release();
            } finally {
                try {
                    outStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    camera.release();
                } 
            }
        }
    };
```

This will show captured image like the one you have mentioned above.

Thank you :)

Comment: here,  if you want more than 4 images on preview, then better use GridLayout, coz managing linear layouts is a bit complicated work.